# mod dav svn apache custom log

Tags: apache, svn, logging, mod-dav-svn

Are there any additional details about the SVN repo or file  that can be logged when creating a custom apache log, besides {SVN-REPOS-NAME} and {SVN-ACTION} with mod dav svn and apache?

```
LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %T}t %u@%h %>s repo:%{SVN-REPOS-NAME}e %{SVN-ACTION}e (%B Bytes in %T Sec)" svn_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/subversion_log svn_log env=SVN-ACTION
```

**UPDATE:**

- I confirm that the target dir is recorded in the log file with no changes to the code above. I only tested on the root repo folder, thus no folder was recorded on the log.
- I confirm that the file is logged also with no changes to the code above, when opened from Tortoise SVN -> Repo Browser, but with a text editor like Notepad++. If the file is opened for example with Internet Explorer, the get-file action is not recorded in the logfile.

The question still stands for info only: Are there additional params that can be added to the LogFormat line ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the `SVN-REPOS` environment variable, which holds the full filesystem path to the repo (as opposed to `SVN-REPOS-NAME`, which only holds the basename). See the section on Apache logging in the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging) for details.

In addition to `SVN-ACTION`, `SVN-REPOS`, and `SVN-REPOS-NAME`, there are [other Apache logging format specifiers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) that you can use to get more details about the *HTTP request* itself, but not about the SVN repo per se.